# postgresql : xml parsing : xpath return only one record, where is xml contains 3 records

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xml-parsing

I have a procedure in postgresql with xml type paramter.
I need to parse xml and insert record in a table.
I tried this way, but it is inserting only one record in table, where as xml contains three records.

the xml code is

```
Select (xpath('/ArrayOfUserGroupModulePermissionBusinessObject/UserGroupModulePermissionBusinessObject/ModuleID/text()', t1))[1]::varchar::BIGINT AS ModuleID
from (Select Perms::xml as t1) as t2;
```

the xml is here

```
<ArrayOfUserGroupModulePermissionBusinessObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UserGroupModulePermissionBusinessObject>
    <UserGroupModulePermissionID>0</UserGroupModulePermissionID>
    <UserGroupID>0</UserGroupID>
    <ModuleID>3</ModuleID>
    <ModuleName>Administration</ModuleName>
    <CanRead>false</CanRead>
    <CanAdd>false</CanAdd>
    <CanEdit>false</CanEdit>
    <CanDelete>false</CanDelete>
    <CanPrint>false</CanPrint>
  </UserGroupModulePermissionBusinessObject>
  <UserGroupModulePermissionBusinessObject>
    <UserGroupModulePermissionID>0</UserGroupModulePermissionID>
    <UserGroupID>0</UserGroupID>
    <ModuleID>2</ModuleID>
    <ModuleName>Data Management</ModuleName>
    <CanRead>false</CanRead>
    <CanAdd>false</CanAdd>
    <CanEdit>false</CanEdit>
    <CanDelete>false</CanDelete>
    <CanPrint>false</CanPrint>
  </UserGroupModulePermissionBusinessObject>
  <UserGroupModulePermissionBusinessObject>
    <UserGroupModulePermissionID>0</UserGroupModulePermissionID>
    <UserGroupID>0</UserGroupID>
    <ModuleID>1</ModuleID>
    <ModuleName>Reception</ModuleName>
    <CanRead>false</CanRead>
    <CanAdd>false</CanAdd>
    <CanEdit>false</CanEdit>
    <CanDelete>false</CanDelete>
    <CanPrint>false</CanPrint>
  </UserGroupModulePermissionBusinessObject>
</ArrayOfUserGroupModulePermissionBusinessObject>
```

I don't know what is wrong in this sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xpath function returns an array with an element for each result. You only use the first element in the array while the array has actually all three elements you expect. Use `unnest` to convert the array to rows.

```
Select unnest(xpath('/ArrayOfUserGroupModulePermissionBusinessObject/UserGroupModulePermissionBusinessObject/ModuleID/text()', t1))::varchar::BIGINT AS ModuleID
from (Select Perms::xml as t1) as t2;
```